# setExact option for AlarmManager and managing previous API levels

Tags: android, api, alarmmanager

I'm using the AlarmManager setExact method to ensure timely execution of alarms, but this is a v19 API feature and I want to make my app compatible with API level 8 (and earlier). My understanding is that API level 8 didn't require this, as the O/S guaranteed timely triggering of alarms, which is fine, but what would be the best way of coding to support API level 8 as well as 19? Do I really need to check the current API level in code, and select a method appropriate to the API level?? Would my app still compile and install on an Android 2.3 device for example if there was an unused method call to the setExact method in my code?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I really need to check the current API level in code, and select a method appropriate to the API level?

Yes, particularly if your `android:targetSdkVersion` is 19 or higher.

> Would my app still compile and install on an Android 2.3 device for example if there was an unused method call to the setExact method in my code?

Yes, so long as you add the `@TargetApi(KITKAT)` annotation to the method, as suggested by Lint, to inform the build system that you indeed are ensuring that you are only calling `setExact()` on `KITKAT` or higher devices.